# For a single 12-2 NM cable, what hole size should be drilled?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I know that code specifies the maximum hole size based on the framing member, but is there a recommended hole size for a single 12-2 NM cable?

Answer (score 3):

Big enough to run the cable through without damaging it.

Personally I would not go smaller than 5/8", and would really say 3/4" minimum, but this is based on experience and practice, nothing more. Typically I use 7/8"-1", but it is rare that I am running only one cable.